# How to redirect using .htaccess in apache?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to create a user management system where users can register another users using  their pre-created user links such as http www .abc .co. uk/access/register.php?id=username [sorry not allowing to put more links]

but I want the long link to be like this:

http://www.abc.co.uk/username

and when users type the short url it will re-direct to http://www.abc.co.uk/access/register.php?id=username

Below are the codes in my .htaccess file at the moment as I am also running a wordpress in the same domain.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./access/register.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Can the .htaccess additional codes that I have added for the username redirect be used along with other wordpress redirect in the same .htaccess file?

When I type the short url in the browser it takes me to a "page not found" page.

I have tried several ways and the above codes does not work. Could anyone please help me? Thanks
Jay

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible. How could apache differentiate between wordpress pages and usernames?

`www.abc.co.uk/contact` could be your contact site or the user “contact”. You need to put your referrer urls in a subfolder, eg. `register` (so you get `abc.co.uk/register/username`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Register
RewriteRule ^/register/(.+)$ ./access/register.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

# Wordpress
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```